# Accessing a MySQL database with php file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database and I am trying to figure out how to access it with a php file. I keep getting an error, so I was wondering if that was because my hostname is incorrect. If so, could anyone help me identify exactly what it is? The database is hosted on this website: https://christopherliao2002.000webhostapp.com/.

Below is my HTML code.

```
    <?php
    //Step1
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','***********','password','******')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');    
    ?>

<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>PHP connect to MySQL</h1>
<?php
//Variables
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "*****";
    $password = "****";
    $dbname = "******";

    //Connection to database
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    //Test connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The best efficient method to connect MySQL from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499815/the-best-efficient-method-to-connect-mysql-from-php)

Comment: You really could have checked your provider's faq: https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/what-is-mysql-hostname-24

Comment: There are tons of tutorials for you. You had to learn them first before asking here.

Comment: Could you reference a few to me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this without the try / catch:

```
    //Variables
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "database_name";

    //Connection to database
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    //Test connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());}
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: When I do that, nothing appears when I open the HTML file on my browser.

Comment: Did you use the right servername, username, password and dbname? And try "localhost" as the servername.

Comment: yea, but it still doesn't work. I've updated the code

Comment: No, just a the words "PHP connect to MySQL"

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: I made an adjustment to the testing code, now this is what it gives me.
connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } echo "Connected successfully"; ?>

Comment: connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } echo "Connected successfully"; ?>

Comment: that is printed on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this format

```
$servername = "localhost"; // This is fixed for 000webhost.
$username = "id***_name";
$password = "****";
$dbname = "id***_name";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is with your hostname. Normally the hostname will be 'localhost' and in 000webhost the hostname is something like mysql#.000webhost.com and '#' needs to be replaced with the number for that  you need to check your hosting providers members area.

And please don't post your username and password publicly

```
$db = mysqli_connect('mysql#.000webhost.com','xxxxx','password','xxxxxx')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');    
?>
```

Comment: Do you know how to find the hosting providers members area number for 000webhost? I've looked in the settings (FTP details), but it doesn't seem to be there...

Comment: Log on to you member area of 000webhost and look for anything related to mysql there they have mentioned the hostname with the correct number.

Comment: Ok, I found it through looking for the host variable. When I use the variable server name in the php section in the body of the code, do I still use the mysql#.000webhost.com or do I use localhost?

Comment: $servername = " mysql4.000webhost.com"; // Here i add 4 as the number and you should use this format as it is a free hosting i believe

Comment: the hostname variable from the database said that its #.000webhost.io. Does the .io make any difference?

Comment: Please exactly use the host name as it is provided by them if it is 4.000webhost.io then use as  $servername = "4.000webhost.io"